# Not able to use sendKeys in dialogue box

Tags: javascript, casperjs, slimerjs

i am using casperJS to import files, and below is the HTML script and picture of the dialogue box

[image: Dialogue box for the file upload]

```
<div class="container">
<p>Import notebooks from another GitHub instance.</p>
<p>Currently import does not preserve history.</p>
<p>
source repo api url: 
<input id="import-source" class="form-control-ext" type="text" value="https://api.github.com" style="width:100%;">
</p>
<p>
notebooks:
<br>
<textarea id="import-gists" class="form-control-ext" form="port" cols="30" rows="10" style="height: 20%;width: 50%;max-width: 100%"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
prefix (e.g.
<code>folder/</code>
to put notebooks in a folder): 
<input id="import-prefix" class="form-control-ext" type="text" style="width:100%;">
</p>
</div>
```

the scenario is i need to enter notebook's ID in notebooks field and click on import. And below is the casperJS code which i have used

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.click({type:'xpath', path:".//*[@id='rcloud-navbar-menu']/li[3]/a"});
    if(this.test.assertVisible('#import_notebooks'),"Import external notebook is visible")
    {
        this.click('#import_notebooks');
    }else
    {
        console.log('Import external notebook is not visible');
    }
    this.wait(2000);
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.sendKeys({type:'css',path:"#import-gists"}, notebookID);
    this.click('.btn.btn-primary');
});
```

The dialogue box opens but not able to enter text in notebooks field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is weird to answer my own question but found the solution.

```
casper.then(function () {
        this.evaluate(function() { $('#import_notebooks').click(); });
        this.echo('opened import notebooks dialog');
        this.wait(2000);
        this.evaluate(function() { $('#import-gists').val('importing Notebook ID'); });
        this.echo('inputted notebook name');
        this.wait(2000);
        this.evaluate(function() { $('#import-prefix').val('Prefix name/'); });
        this.echo('inputted prefix');
        this.wait(2000);
        this.evaluate(function() { $('#import-notebooks-dialog span.btn-primary').click(); });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`casper.test.assertVisible()` doesn't return a boolean denoting the result of the assertion. It returns a result object. That line is also not syntactically sound.

What you probably wanted to use, is `casper.visible()`:

```
if(this.visible('#import_notebooks')) {
    this.click('#import_notebooks');
} else {
    console.log('Import external notebook is not visible');
}
```

Comment: the dialogue box opens but not able to enter text in those fields...is there any possible way to do it other than sendKeys()

Comment: and when i ran the above casper script, it opens the box and in console it displays: 'addons.repository WARN cacheEnabled: Couldn't get pref: extensions.getAddons.cache.enabled'

Comment: How do you know that the fields aren't filled? Have you taken a screenshot?

Comment: i am not running it in headless, i can see the operations performing